# RC Series circuit's voltages

Tags: voltage, series, proteus

I made this simulation circuit using Proteus.

[image: at the simulation]

In this I connected a AC source 200V RMS/50Hz.
But, sum of capacitor voltage and lamp voltage not equal to given 200V. What is the reason for that?

According to calculation of Xc(Capacitor reactance) and lamp resistant and using the voltage divider rule capacitor voltage and lamp voltage equal to given 200V.

What is the reason for this difference?

Comment: Your capacitor and your lamp are not in phase, so the voltages across them aren't either.

Comment: Yes..Voltage of capacitor lag. Can you explain please  @SomeoneSomewhere

Comment: Voltage across the capacitor lags the current through it by \$\small 90^o\$, because voltage is obtained from the integral of current and sine integrates to -cosine. The voltage and current are in-phase for the lamp (assumed resistive), so the two voltages are \$\small 90^o\$ different. Pythagoras gives \$\small \sqrt{100^2+173^2}=200\$

Comment: @Chu Did you assume capacitor is a pure capacitor? If it is not a pure one cant we apply Pythagoras like this?

Answer (score 1):

Vsupply = \$\sqrt{173^2 + 100^2}\$ = 199.8 volts.

The current through the capacitor and lamp is the same but the voltages across them are 90 degrees out of phase hence you have to solve with pythagorus: -

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Its a simple now. I can remember my old memories.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with matlab,

```
>> Epp = 200*sqrt(2)

Epp =

  282.8427

>> Z=-i*(1/(2*pi*50*14.7e-6))

Z =

   0.0000e+00 - 2.1654e+02i

>> R=125;
>> 
>> VC = Z*Epp/(Z+R)

VC =

   2.1212e+02 - 1.2245e+02i

>> VR = R*Epp/(Z+R)

VR =

   7.0685e+01 + 1.2245e+02i

>> abs(VC+VR)

ans =

  282.8427

>>
```

Comment: Thanks. I have to learn metlab..
why use "-i" for this `Z=-i*(1/(2*pi*50*14.7e-6))`?

Comment: Because the capacitor impedance is $$Z_C = -i \frac{1}{2 \pi f C}.$$ It is easy to proof plugging into the capacitor equation, a generic sinusoidal wave.

Answer (score 1):

Using a 2 channel scope, one probe on AC input, and one probe on common node of both R & C, you get this attenation (VOut is approximately 50% of vin) and delayed. The input is 200MHz sin, the LPF RC is 100MHz.

[image]